# Why am I getting unknown column when the column exists?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, rspec, rails-migrations

When running my spec for photos#star, I'm not sure why I am getting the unknown column error for stars.user_id when the column actually exists. The action works fine in the rails console and in the browser in that the @user.starred_photos actually gets modified.

I've checked the database schema in mysql and the column is there. I've tried rolling back the migration and redoing it as well as restarting the server. This is the error:

```
Failure/Error:
   expect{
     post :star, id: photo
   }.to change{ @user.starred_photos.count }.from(0).to(1)

 ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
   Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'stars.user_id' in 'where clause': SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `photos` INNER JOIN `stars` ON `photos`.`id` = `stars`.`photo_id` WHERE `stars`.`user_id` = 1
```

Controller spec & action

```
# spec/controllers/photos_controller_spec.rb   
describe '#POST star' do
    it "adds the given photo to the user's starred photos" do
        sign_in_as_user
        other_user = create(:user)
        photo = other_user.photos.create(attributes_for(:photo))

        expect{
            post :star, id: photo
        }.to change{ @user.starred_photos.count }.from(0).to(1)
    end
end


#app/controllers/photos_controller.rb
def star
    current_user.starred_photos << @photo
end
```

Models

```
# app/models/star.rb
class Star < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :photo
end

# app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :photos
  has_many :stars
  has_many :starred_photos, through: :stars, source: :photo

# app/models/photo.rb
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :stars
  has_many :starring_users, through: :stars, source: :user
```

Schema

```
# db/schema.rb
create_table "stars", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "photo_id",   limit: 4
    t.integer  "user_id",    limit: 4
    t.datetime "created_at",           null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",           null: false
end
```

I'm having one of those days and I suspect I'm missing something really obvious here. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show your `database.yml` file?

Comment: Check your version of mysql and the version of the gem you are using. I had similar issues in the past, usually restarting mysql service solved it temporaly for me. Never investigated what was causing the issue, but updating to the last mysql / mysql2 gem solved it for good.

Comment: Try running `rake db:test:prepare` to update your test schema from your dev database.

Comment: Thank you all for your responses, @RobertNube's suggestion worked perfectly. I hope others can benefit from seeing his comment if they ever get stuck like me.

Comment: @SajadTorkamani: cool. I wrote the comment as an answer below, with a bit more detail, for posterity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test database has likely not had your migrations applied to it yet. You can run `rake db:test:prepare` to copy your development database schema to your test database, then try running your tests again. Or, you can just run `rake spec` -- by default, that command will prepare your test database before running any tests.